# Project documents managing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, documentation, project

I'm using Eclipse with Maven integration. I wonder what is the best way to persist project documentation. For example the description and UML diagrams. I do not want to use systems like Dropbox and Google Drive since my project would be "spread" then. Maybe a good solution would be to place the files into the resources folder?

Any ideas?

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409839/where-to-locate-my-uml-diagram-files-in-my-maven-project-structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to create a *site*, as described in the [Maven site documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-site.html). Here is the [site plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/).

With the site plugin, you can generate a project site containing all the documentation you need.

The resources folder is not a good idea, because resources will be packaged in the build.